# php-config shell script needed

Tags: php, gcc, configuration, compilation

I want to compile extension for PHP under Windows and I need to run such command:

```
g++ `php-config --includes` -fPIC -c some_script.cpp
```

but when I run this command I received an error:

```
g++: error: `php-config: No such file or directory
g++: error: unrecognized option '--includes`'
```

where can I get php-config shell script without recompiling PHP (under Windows)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that you don't have the script, it's that the Windows shell doesn't know what you're trying to do because it doesn't support backticks.   The command wants to run the `php-config` script and include the output in the command, but instead `g++` is being passed `\`php-config`as the first argument, and`--includes`` as the second argument, which are not valid arguments to GCC.

You can't run a UNIX shell command in Windows. Either use a UNIX-style shell (e.g. via Cygwin or Mingw32) or just use a different command, e.g. figure out what the necessary include flags are and use them:

```
g++ -I/some/path -fPIC -c some_script.cpp
```